# Selected option in dropdownlist in yii

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

How can I have a default selected option in a dropdownlist in Yii? And then when the user enter my view the data would be displayed automatically?For example I pass some months via an action January, February etc and I want to have preselected the current month and when the user enters my view he should see the data from the current month? I think I have to play with javascript but I'm having trouble with the syntax because I'm fairly new to this.
This is my view:

```
<?php    
?>
     <div class="panel panel-primary">
           <div class="panel-heading">
                <?php

    echo $schoolclass->description;
?>                 
     </div>
     </div>    
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">  
   <?php   
            $presentsData = CHtml::listData($presentmonths, 'presentmonth','presentmonth');
            echo CHtml::dropDownList('presentmonthlist', 'presentmonth', $presentsData,
      array(
                'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('present/viewmonthlypresents',array('id'=>$schoolclass->schoolclassid)),
                            'update'=>'#mypresents',
                            'data'=>array('presentmonth'=>'js:this.value')                      
                  )
            )); 
    ?>   
    </div>
        </div>     
<div id="mypresents">    
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
 <?php echo CHtml::button(Yii::t('default' ,'Submit Presents'), array(
     'submit'=>array('create', 'id'=>$schoolclass->schoolclassid)    
     )
 );                
 ?>        
   </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I dont have any errors yet. My view works fine but I want to change it a bit so that the preselected value should be the current month (April) and then display the data. To make it more clear when a user goes to my view I want to have the current month preselecet and automatically display the data from that month. That's why I said above that I think I have to use Javascript somehow for this but I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

you can set default selected option like this, for example i used 'January'

```
 echo CHtml::dropDownList('presentmonthlist', 'January', $presentsData,
      array(


                'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('present/viewmonthlypresents',array('id'=>$schoolclass->schoolclassid)),
                            'update'=>'#mypresents',
                            'data'=>array('presentmonth'=>'js:this.value')

                  )
            ));
```

Comment: thanx for the quick answer! I want for starters my default value to be the current month. Now we have Arpil so can i use something like this date('Y-m-d') to set the default value as the current month?

Comment: yes you can do like that, you can use php Date function like this, $currentMonth = date('F');
$month =  Date('F', strtotime($currentMonth));

Comment: ok i think its working like that. But now how can I display the data from the current month automatically (without clicking on the dropdownlist) when a user goes to that view? Should I set options in the dropdown with id or something like that and then use javascript to autoload the data?

Comment: yes you can use id or class and do it in loading time

Comment: Well that is my question actually and because I'm new in Yii I get lost in translation. I found around the internet that options are set like this somehow:options'=>array('id'=>array('selected'=>true)) and then how can I take that and pass it to a javascript function which will automatically load the data from the current month?

Comment: if you are using form model say, $form->dropDownList() then you can set default dropdown value like this array("0"=>array('selected'=>true)) ( where 0 is index value of dropdown option),  but you are using chtml::dropDownList() so the second parameter is default selected option for like in my answer

Comment: ok so how can take this parameter and pass it to a javascript function which will automatically display the data when a user goes to my view?without clicking the dropdown box? because now it just returns the month and when i click the dropdown box it returns the rest of the data. I want to auto-load the data from the current month

Comment: I want to auto-load the data from the current month means?? what you want to load?

Comment: in the ajax post I if you see I create a url in anotheraction. Called ViewMonthlyPresents. This actions renders partial another view which loads the data from the db. The data are html tables with header some dates and names and the cells are just zeros or aces. I want to autoload those data in the view when a user enters the view I currently am. I hope I was clear enough. If you want to see the code from the other view ask me.

Comment: use this ajax part---> 'ajax' => array(
                                'type'=>'POST',
                                'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('present/viewmonthlypresents',array('id'=>$schoolclass->schoolclassid)),
                                'data'=>array('presentmonth'=>'js:this.value'),
                                'success'=>'function(response) {
                                        $("#mypresents").html(response);
                                }',
                        )

Comment: thanx i tried that but it doesnt work. Maybe the problem is that I renderpartial another view from the ajax post in order to fetch the data. And this view is empty as you can see.

Comment: try to give hardcoded value in ajax like this --->  'data'=>array('presentmonth'=>'January')